# Eclipse GMF Background Image of an Editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-gmf

I want to tile a GIF- Image (as background texture) on the background of my GMF diagram editor like Graphiti's background style.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/GMF_Newsgroup_Q_and_A#How_to_scroll_a_background_image.3F